# Express, React, & Webpack: CORS Preflight issue - can't pass headers in GET

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, webpack-dev-server

React 16 and Node 9.9 on MacOS. Using Webpack Dev Server to test. I'm trying to pass headers in a GET request and they do not make it through.

On the server I'm allowing everything:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, value1, value2, value3");
    next();
});
```

My client request is made with Axios, like so:

```
const request = axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `http://my.api.co/endpoint`,
    headers: {
        "value1": "1",
        "value2": "2",
        "value3": "3"
    }
});
```

When checking the incoming request, req.headers does not contain these values but I can see the keys (not the values) in the request.

I see:

```
req.headers.access-control-request-headers:"value1,value2,value3"
```

...and same in req.rawHeaders. But I cannot get my hands on the values - they're not coming through. I cannot access the following, for example:

```
req.headers.value1
```

I think this has something to do w/ "preflight" but am unsure how to solve the issue after hunting around. Not finding a straight answer. I would need this for every type of request, not just GET. How can I pass headers to the server from Axios?

Is the issue strictly with webpack-dev-server? Will I see a difference when I'm not using it? If it's going to be different in production, I'd definitely like to know what my steps are.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, simple mistake on my part. The middleware in the OP needed to be moved above the middleware block where I'm actually checking for those header values. I misunderstood how it works. All good now!